# How to call internal method with internal delegate argument from different assembly by reflection?

Tags: c#, reflection

I do not have a source code for a type and need to call an internal method with an internal argument.

Is there a way to do something like this: `Set.InOrderTreeWalk((object o) => o != null)` ?

```
namespace assembly_1
{
    internal delegate bool TreeWalkPredicate<T>(Set<T>.Node node);
    public class Set<T>
    {
        private Node[] nodes;
        internal bool InOrderTreeWalk(TreeWalkPredicate<T> action)
        {
            foreach (var node in nodes)
            {
                if (!action(node))
                    return false;
            }

            return true;
        }

        internal class Node
        {
            public T Item;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i'm confused? if you don't have the source then what's this source?

Comment: @Daniel A. White, Jetbrains' dotpeak helps me

Comment: @elgonzo, the title contains the tricky point in this case - internal delegate as an argument

Comment: @Alew, yeah, you are right, the argument being an (internal) delegate makes this a bit troublesome...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before I get into it, *insert standard disclaimer about how implementation details are internal for a reason and the author doesn't owe you an explanation if something changes and it breaks your reflection code.*

---

On the surface, the fact that the argument is of an internal delegate type does make this a bit troublesome, but there's actually a convenient way to get it: get the `MethodInfo` for the method we want to call and then examine its parameter.

Let's assume we already have this variable with an instance assigned:

```
Set<MyNode> set;
```

...and that the `MyNode` type has been declared somewhere.  We want `Set<MyNode>.InOrderTreeWalk` to call the following method for each node in the set:

```
private bool MyPredicate(Set<MyNode>.Node node)
{
    return true;
}
```

There's not much to it, just follow the comments:

```
// Get the method we want to call.
MethodInfo inOrderTreeWalkMethod = set.GetType().GetMethod(
    "InOrderTreeWalk", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

// Get the internal delegate type from the parameter info.  The type retrieved here
// is already close-constructed so we don't have to do any generic-related manipulation.
Type treeWalkPredicateType = inOrderTreeWalkMethod.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType;

// Get the method we want to be called for each node.
MethodInfo myPredicateMethod = GetType().GetMethod(
    nameof(MyPredicate), BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

// Create the delegate.  This is where the magic happens.  The runtime validates
// type compatibility and throws an exception if something's wrong.
Delegate myPredicateDelegate = myPredicateMethod.CreateDelegate(treeWalkPredicateType, this);

// Call the internal method and pass our delegate.
bool result = (bool)inOrderTreeWalkMethod.Invoke(set, new object[] { myPredicateDelegate });
```

Assuming you've provided enough information about the component you're using, and barring any issues with trust level, that should do it.

Comment: It is not possible to declare method with inaccessible argument type.

Comment: @Alew - That's okay because you don't have to. Your goal is to call `InOrderTreeWalk` and have it call your own method with a *compatible* signature. This will do exactly that. Reflection deals with matching your compatible signature to the runtime-discovered type and passing a value of that (delegate) type to the method -- all in the last two lines.